ERROR: Could not build wheels for chromedriver-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Error
Not able to install chromedriver-binary any version
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chromedriver-binary
  Running setup.py clean for chromedriver-binary
Failed to build chromedriver-binary
ERROR: Could not build wheels for chromedriver-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried updating setuptools and wheel - it didn't help
I couldn't find the answer online
Python version 3.9.0

